# Define exclusive select element with jQuery selectable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I've two ol elements with li inside and I'd like to allow to select in `ol#gardien` only one element and in the `ol#milieu` several elements. How I can do that with jQuery?

HTML:

```
<ol id="gardien" class="selectable ui-selectable">
<li class="ui-widget-content">Olivier</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content">Arnaud</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content">Rémy</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content">Willy</li>
</ol>

<ol id="milieu" class="selectable ui-selectable">
<li class="ui-widget-content">Alain</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content">Loic</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content">Benoît</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Which li elements do you want to select?

Comment: how do you want to select them? jquery ui?

Comment: Can you define _several elements_ in context?

Comment: I want to give the possibility to the user to select with its mouse only one element in the "gardien" ol and more than one in the milieu ol. Yes with jquery ui. At this stage I use $(".selectable").bind("mousedown", function(e) {e.metaKey = true;}).selectable(); to allow user to select elements but how I can do to restrict the selection in the first ol ?

Comment: @all you can test it here -> http://jsfiddle.net/d8gBe/

Comment: I don't understand your point. Only one li in ol can be select in both... What I'm trying to do is to select >1 li in one ol (#milieu) and exactly one li in (#gardien)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`selected`](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selected) event, in this event you can remove the selected element and select the new one.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#milieu").selectable();

    $("#gardien").selectable({
        selected: function (event, ui) {
            $(ui.selected).addClass("ui-selected").siblings().removeClass("ui-selected");
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RwYxb/

Comment: Is working for me, at the end of select event only one element is selected

Comment: yes, but I wanted to have the possibility to select multiple elements in one ol and only one (default behavior) in the second ol.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is to separate in two those I want to have multilple selection and the one with only one selection.

Multiple selection :

```
$("#milieu").bind("mousedown", function(e) {e.metaKey = true;}).selectable();
```

Only one selection is possible (default behavior in jquery)

```
$("#gardien" ).selectable();
```